# Deleting random nodes in a directed graph and no in-neighbors in Networkx

Tags: graph, network-programming, nodes, networkx

I am working lately with Networkx and I would like to create a code that performs some extinction experiments following these steps:

1. Eliminate in each iteration one node

As long as there are disconnected nodes:

- Eliminate the disconnected nodes
- Eliminate nodes with no in-neighbors

I can't find a simple way to detect nodes with no in-neighbors in the graph

I have build up a small experiment(i am stuck with the elimination of nodes with no in-neighbors):

Given an initial adjacency matrix

```
mat = np.array([[0,1,1,1,0,1],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0],
                [1,0,0,1,0,0]])    #Experiment adjacency matrix

G = nx.from_numpy_array(mat,create_using=nx.DiGraph)


print("Number of species ", G.number_of_nodes())
print("Number of links ", G.number_of_edges())
```

[Initial Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax1Lj.png)

If i remove the node 0, the disconnected nodes (2,1,4) must be removed too. I follow the following steps:

```
G.remove_node(0)
G.remove_nodes_from(list(nx.isolates(G))) #Find disconnected nodes and eliminate them

nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

[Updated graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D3BM.png)

Now as I have a node with no in-neighbors (node 5), i would like to find a easy way to detect this nodes and to eliminate them in a generalized matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the in-degree of a node using the `nx.DiGraph.in_degree` method:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph([(5, 3)])
in_degree = dict(G.in_degree())
# InDegreeView({5: 0, 3: 1})
for node, degree in in_degree.items():
    if degree == 0:
        G.remove_node(node)
```